# How can I get my 15 month old Dachshund to quit licking my other dog's pee?

Tags: dogs, behavior, toilet-training, socializing, dachshunds

My older female Dachshund goes out to pee and the male Dachshund, whose name is Buster, licks her per and he's constantly in there faces; the two don't like it and I am at wits' end about it.

Comment: Welcome to Pets! Please take the [tour], it only takes a minute.  Are they both (or one of them) desexed? Please [edit] your question to add some more information.

Comment: Related: https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/11374/why-does-my-dog-drink-another-dogs-pee