# Dog drinking his pee

Tags: behavior

My dog has just started drinking his pee when he goes outside in the grass and then he start chattering his teeth like you do when your freezing but its hot outside

Comment: Does this help: [Why is my dog drinking his pee after he urinates inside?](http://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/473/why-is-my-dog-drinking-his-pee-after-he-urinates-inside?rq=1)